# starting LXDE automatically (without Display Manager)

Tags: login, window-manager, lxde, login-manager, xinit

I am disappointed with existing Display Managers, and so I was wondering wheteher I could live without one. I have very basic needs on my laptop. I have one user `martin` who wants to be logged into `LXDE` automatically after boot.

I have made following change in `/etc/inittab`

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
1:2345:once:/bin/login -f martin tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

and added following line to my `/home/martin/.profile`

```
xinit 2>/dev/null
```

Now, when I boot my laptop, `LXDE` starts automatically. Thats great. When I log out of `LXDE`, I am back in `tty1`, logged in as `martin`. The problem is, when `LXDE` is running and I have screen-lock active to protect my `LXDE` session, somebody could press <kbd>CTRL+c</kbd> in `tty1`, thereby killing LXDE and he would be logged in as `martin`.

Is there a way to make `LXDE` start without leaving martin logged in on `tty1`? i.e., after `LXDE` has started, I don't need `tty1` anymore and I would like to log out of it. but I cannot because `LXDE` is started from that console. Is there any way to make `LXDE` to "detach" itself from `tty1`, so that is shows the standard `login` prompt as normally?

In case it is relevant, I am using Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use small footprint Display Manager.

SLIM

With this display manager, some manual configuration is needed. Please refer to their official document and write your /etc/slim.conf and ~/.xinitrc. The command you should put in your ~/.xinitrc to start LXDE is:

exec startlxde

The above is coming from : http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Debian

It supports autologin.

Comment: The problem with `gdm` or `kdm` is, that they are too overbloated. Look at their dependencies. That is insane. `gdm` wants to install 150 MB of additional packages, that is more than the whole of `LXDE`. `kdm` is even worse (150 new packages, 335 MB). Hello?. The only thing I want from a Display Manager is to log me into LXDE.

Comment: slim then? I don't know it but the name speaks for itself.. Check the wiki link, there is more..

Comment: I have been using `wdm` up until now. The problem is, `wdm` does not support autologin. Otherwise `wdm` would be good.

Comment: it seems you can with slim.

Comment: does `slim` support autologin ?

Comment: yes here an example with archlinux, I guess it would similar with Debian ( for the conf file I mean)

Comment: although not answering my original question, slim seems to be a good solution to my problem